# Groovy Node.depthFirst() returning a List of Nodes and Strings?

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xmlnode, xmlslurper

I'm hoping someone will just point out something obvious that I'm missing here. I feel like I've done this a hundred times and for some reason tonight, the behavior coming from this is throwing me for a loop.

I'm reading in some XML from a public API. I want to extract all the text from a certain node (everything within 'body'), which also includes a variety of child nodes. Simple example:

```html
<xml>
    <metadata>
        <article>
            <body>
                <sec>
                    <title>A Title</title>
                    <p>
                        This contains 
                        <italic>italics</italic> 
                        and
                        <xref ref-type="bibr">xref's</xref>
                        .
                    </p>
                </sec>
                <sec>
                    <title>Second Title</title>
                </sec>
            </body>
        </article>
    </metadata>
</xml>
```

So ultimately I want to traverse the tree within the desired node (again, 'body') and extract all the text contained in its natural order. Simple enough, so I just write up this little Groovy script...

```java
def xmlParser = new XmlParser()
def xml = xmlParser.parseText(rawXml)
xml.metadata.article.body[0].depthFirst().each { node ->
    if(node.children().size() == 1) {
        println node.text()
    }   
}
```

...which proceeds to blow up with "No signature of method: java.lang.String.children()". So I'm thinking to myself "wait, what? Am I going crazy?" Node.depthFirst() should only return a List of Node's. I add a little 'instanceof' check and sure enough, I'm getting a combination of Node objects and String objects. Specifically the lines not within entities on the same line are returned as String's, aka "This contains" and "and". Everything else is a Node (as expected).

I can work around this easily. However, this doesn't seem like correct behavior and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Node.depthFirst behaved as you would expect in groovy 1.7.  In groovy 2.0+, I'm seeing the same results of Nodes/Strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's correct behavior (though I've always found the XmlSlurper and XmlParser to have screwy APIs).  All things you can iterate through really should implement a node interface IMO and potentially have a `type` of `TEXT` that you could use to know to get the text from them.

Those text nodes are valid nodes that in many cases you'd want to hit as it did a depth first traversal through the XML.  If they didn't get returned, your algorithm for checking if the children size of 1 wouldn't work because some nodes (like the `<p>` tag) has both mixed text and elements underneath it.

Also, why `depthFirst` doesn't consistently return all text nodes where the text is the only child, such as for `italic` above, makes things even worse.

I tend to like to use the signature of groovy methods to let the runtime figure out which is the right way to handle each node (rather than using something like `instanceof`) like this:

```
def rawXml = """<xml>
    <metadata>
        <article>
            <body>
                <sec>
                    <title>A Title</title>
                    <p>
                        This contains 
                        <italic>italics</italic> 
                        and
                        <xref ref-type="bibr">xref's</xref>
                        .
                    </p>
                </sec>
                <sec>
                    <title>Second Title</title>
                </sec>
            </body>
        </article>
    </metadata>
</xml>"""

def processNode(String nodeText) {
    return nodeText
}

def processNode(Object node) {
   if(node.children().size() == 1) {
       return node.text()
   }
}

def xmlParser = new XmlParser()
def xml = xmlParser.parseText(rawXml)
def xmlText = xml.metadata.article.body[0].'**'.findResults { node ->
    processNode(node)
}

println xmlText.join(" ")
```

Prints

```
A Title This contains italics and xref's .  Second Title
```

Alternatively, the `XmlSlurper` class probably does more what you want/expect it to and has a more reasonable set of output from the `text()` method.  If you really don't need to do any sort of DOM walking with the results (what `XmlParser` is "better" for), I'd suggest `XmlSlurper`:

```
def xmlParser = new XmlSlurper()
def xml = xmlParser.parseText(rawXml)
def bodyText = xml.metadata.article.body[0].text()
println bodyText
```

Prints:

```
A Title
                    This contains 
                    italics 
                    and
                    xref's
                    .
                Second Title
```

Comment: The last tidbit is all I really want and exactly what I was expecting. I could have sworn I tried that, but I must have just left the depthFirst() in there every time which was throwing me for a loop.

Comment: Oh, that and the fact that GPathResult.text() behaves very differently than Node.text(). I wish the docs were a bit more informative...

Comment: Can you please eleborate the meaning of Double "*"

Comment: @Shashank.gupta40 `'**'` is shorthand for `depthFirst()`